# Алгоритм создания футбольного календаря

Tags: алгоритм, php, sql

Итак, как-то пытался придумать такой алгоритм, но видать не придумал, сейчас снова пытаюсь такое реализовать.
Все, кто разбираются в футболе, знают, что в чемпионате есть календарь игр. В каждом туре играют все команды 1 игру. Кол-во туров зависит от кол-ва команд.

```
Пример:

Команда1
Команда2
Команда3
Команда4

**Календарь**
Круг 1 (все играют со всеми)
**Тур 1**
Команда1 - Команда2
Команда3 - Команда4

**Тур 2**
Команда2 - Команда3
Команда4 - Команда1

**Тур 3**
Команда1 - Команда3
Команда2 - Команда4

Круг 2 (тоже самое но только команды меняются полями, т.е. местами)
**Тур 4**
Команда2 - Команда1
Команда4 - Команда3

**Тур 5**
Команда3 - Команда2
Команда1 - Команда4

**Тур 6**
Команда3 - Команда1
Команда4 - Команда2
```

P.S.: Реализовываться это будет скорее всего на php, но важен алгоритм.

Comment: и все равно код ниже не правильно работает...
например в 1 туре получается есть игры 1 - 2 и 2 - 16, т.е. 2 играет две игры.
мда... пожалуй и правда сначала нужно математически это решить а уже потом браться за код....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно еще методом грубой силы. Случайно выбирая пары и проверяя, что они еще не играли.

Т.е. цикл по турам. Выбираем пару. Упорядочиваем ее по номеру команд. Смотрим (в хэше), если их нет там, то добавляем в хэш, в расписание и уменьшаем счетчик игр в туре (его начальное значение известно). Как счетчик обнулится переходим к новому туру.

Выбор пар наверное можно оптимизировать, чтобы поменьше вычислять случайные числа.

***UPDATE***

Другой вариант просто посчитать по турам. Я сделал на C. Судя по результатам работы алгоритм **не оптимален** для количества команд не равным степени 2-х. **Но он работает**

```
/*
  avp 2012

  Таблица чемпионата (один круг) 
  n команд (аргумент командной строки)

  Составление расписания по турам
  Количество туров вычисляется в программе

  В stdout выводится список туров с парами команд 
  и квалратная таблица номеров туров для команд
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct cmd {  // данные каждой команды
  int ic,     // номер команды (с нуля)
    ng;       // количество уже проведенных игр (init 0)
};

/*
  Сортировать команды по возрастанию проведенных игр
  (у кого меньше в начало списка)
  n - размер списка команд
 */
void
sort (struct cmd a[], // список команд
      int n)
{
  int i, j;

  for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    struct cmd tt = a[i];
    for (j = i; j > 0; j--) {
      if (a[j].ng >= a[j-1].ng)
        break;
      a[j] = a[j-1];
    } 
    if (j < i)
      a[j] = tt;
  }

}

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int n = 10;  // количество команд в чемпионате
  if (ac > 1)
    if ((n = atoi(av[1])) < 2)
      n = 10;

  int game[n][n];    // в каком туре играют j,k (туры с 1, номера команд с 0)
  int tot = (n*(n-1))/2; // общее количество игр в круге
  int cal[tot][n];   // с кем в туре i играет команда j (все индексы с 0)

  int i,j,k, jc, kc, // разные индексы
    ng, // количество уже проведенных игр в круге
    nt; // количество туров (вычисляетя в ходе составления расписания)

  // инициализация таблицы игр в круге
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      game[i][j] = 0;  // здесь будет в каком туре играют команды i,j
    }
    game[i][i] = -1;
  }
  // инициализация таблицы по турам (количество туров с большим запасом)
  for (i = 0; i < tot; i++) 
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      cal[i][j] = 0; /* здесь будет с какой командой (номер с 1)
                        в туре i (индекс с 0) играет команда j (индекс с 0)
                     */

  struct cmd a[n]; // список команд
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a[i].ic = i;
    a[i].ng = 0;
  }

  // собственно вычисления
  for (i = ng = 0; ng < tot; i++) { // увеличиваем туры (i) пока не сыграли
                                    // все матчи круга (ng)
    sort(a,n); // это для равномерности (?) по турам
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) { // перебираем команды из списка
      jc = a[j].ic;
      if (cal[i][jc])
         continue;   // уже играла в этом туре
      for (k = 0; k < n; k++) { // перебираем команды из списка
         kc = a[k].ic;
         if (kc == jc)
            continue; // сама с собой
         if (cal[i][kc] || game[jc][kc])
            continue; // kc уже играла в туре или играла раньше с jc
         /*
           kc и jc еще не играли. Пусть сыграют в этом туре
           увеличим количество проведенных игр и заполним таблицы
         */
         ng++;
         a[jc].ng++;
         a[kc].ng++;
         cal[i][kc] = jc+1;
         cal[i][jc] = kc+1;
         game[jc][kc] = i+1;
         game[kc][jc] = i+1;
         break;
      }
    }
  }
  nt = i; // это сколько туров получилось.

  // печать игр по турам
  printf ("ntours %d\n",nt);
  for (i = 0; i < nt; i++) {
    printf ("tour %d\n",i+1);
    int t[n];
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      t[j] = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      if (k = cal[i][j]) {
        if (!t[k-1]) {
        // printf ("%2d:%2d ",j+1,k);
           printf (" %c : %c  ",'A'+j,'A'+k-1);
           t[j] = t[k-1] = 1;
        }
      }
    }
    printf ("\n");
  }

  // печать квадратной таблицы туров для команд
  printf ("\ntours table\n");
  printf ("    ");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    //    printf ("%2d ",i+1);
    printf (" %c ",'A'+i);
  printf ("\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    //    printf (" %2d ",i+1);
    printf (" %c  ",'A'+i);
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      printf ("%2d ",game[i][j]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
  }
  printf ("\n");
}
```

Уважаемый [[@namak](/users/2140/namak)](/users/2140/namak), Вы уж извините меня за программу на Си. Я понимаю, что Вы спрашивали PHP с SQL, но Си я владею значительно лучше, а алгоритм надеюсь будет понятен.

**Алгоритм (операторы)** собственно находится между комментариями

// собственно вычисления

и

// печать игр по турам

**UPDATE 2**

Функция перемешивающая команды (вместо sort())

```
void
shuffle (struct cmd a[], int n)
{
  int i, j;
  static int first = 1;
  if (first) {
    first = 0;
    srand(time(0));
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    struct cmd tt;
    j = rand()%n;
    tt = a[j];
    a[j] = a[i];
    a[i] = tt;
  }

}
```

Comment: ла без разницы на каком языке, переписать на php не проблема, если конечно тут нет ничего специфического от C.
ща попробуем на Сишке проверить что получается

Comment: ваш код позволяет обрабатывать нечетное коилчество команд тоже?

Comment: Да, любое > 1

Comment: Нашел 2 маленькие ошибочки:

1. в sort a[j].ng >= a[j-1].ng надо, естественно, заменить на tt.ng >= a[j-1].ng

2. в основной части вместо          a[jc].ng++; a[kc].ng++; надо

         a[j].ng++;
         a[k].ng++;

Но в целом результаты не изменились.

Comment: Как сделать оптимальное расписание не знаю. Интересные результаты получаются, если вместо sort() использовать функцию случайно перемешивающую команды между турами. От запуска к запуску количество туров **меняется !**. Вы можете использовать эту идею для вычисления расписания с минимумом туров. Функцию привожу в **UPDATE 2**

Answer (score 2):

В бд таблица `matches`, поля `id`, `tour`, `team1`, `team2`, `scores`

Алгоритм где-то так...

```
for ($i=1; $i<=16; $i++) { // для 16 команд
  for ($j=$i+1; $j<=16; $j++) { // таки начнем с +1, прошу прощения
    $tour_id_1 = ($i + $j - 2) % 15;
    if ($tour_id_1 == 0) $tour_id_1 = 15;
    $tour_id_2 = 31 - $tour_id_1; // 2-ой круг по "зеркальной" системе, при потребности подмените использованые числа
    $team_1 = $i; // здесь - условный индекс команды. легко поддается переделке в ваш id. надеюсь, вы не названия команд напрямую в календарь собираетесь заносить? :)
    $team_2 = $j; // не забудьте на ответный матч поменять хозяев и гостей местами
    // дальше - дописываете mysql-запрос, который создаст в БД требуемые поля
  }
}
// при потребности на этом уровне можно будет перетасовать туры. если выберете для хранения массив, объект или коллекцию, то сможете сделать превращение с использованием временного массива etc.
```

Алгоритм есть. По вопросам дискретной математики консультирует [другой форум](http://math.hashcode.ru/).

Comment: это что то даже на легкий намек не похоже)
меня не интересует покупка данного скрипта, меня алгоритм интересует, можно просто на словах как вообще можно такое сделать.

Comment: это и не был намек) был на паре, и время подходило к концу. сейчас отредактирую комментарий выше

Comment: такс, все равно не вижу ничего...
здесь просто создадутся туры, а $i и $j у нас ведь одинаковые, поэтому в $team_1 и $team_2 тоже будут одинаковыми. что то не то...

Comment: по +1 - fixed, по тому, что присваиваю в $team_1 & $team_2 - закомментировал

Comment: $tour_id_2 получается неправильным. даже если к 30 - $tour_id_1 добавить +1, все равно получается что одна команда в 1 туре играет 2 игры. а если оставить как у вас, то присутствуют тур, второй круг, как бы смещен на 1 тур. т.е. туры от 0, а не от 1

Comment: третья строка, -2 вместо -1

Comment: тогда получаем для матча между командами 1 и 2 1-ый тур и дальше по аналогии. 31 - 1 = 30, последний тур соответсвенно

Comment: все равно неправильно.
получается что 1 тур кол-во матчей 1 штука, 2 тур - кол-во 2 штуки,... 15 тур - кол-во 15 штук, и потом убывает кол-во от 15 до 1.

Answer (score 2):

Все намного проще чем вы думаете. Начнем с того, что в начале сезона команды расположены на тех позициях на которых они его закончили.

Всего команд `n`, каждой команде надо сыграть `n-1` матчей. Любые 2 команды играют между собой по 2 раза (один раз дома, а второй раз на выезде). Выходит общее количество матчей `n * (n - 1)`

Матчи в начале сезона идут следующем порядке:

```
1 vs (n-1) // 1 место с последним
2 vs (n-2) // 2 место с предпоследним
...
```

вот расписание лиги из одного футбльного онлайн менеджера, можете в эту решетку случайным образом подставить id ваших комманд.

```
неделя  1
    A - B
    C - D
    E - F
    G - H
неделя  2
    H - E
    F - A
    B - C
    D - G
неделя  3
    E - B
    G - C
    H - F
    A - D
неделя  4
    D - E
    F - G
    C - A
    B - H
неделя  5
    G - B
    E - A
    H - C
    F - D
неделя  6
    C - E
    D - H
    A - G
    B - F
неделя  7
    F - C
    E - G
    H - A
    D - B
неделя  8
    A - H
    C - F
    G - E
    B - D
неделя  9
    E - C
    F - B
    G - A
    H - D
неделя  10
    A - E
    D - F
    B - G
    C - H
неделя  11
    E - D
    H - B
    A - C
    G - F
неделя  12
    C - G
    B - E
    F - H
    D - A
неделя  13
    C - B
    A - F
    G - D
    E - H
неделя  14
    B - A
    D - C
    F - E
    H - G
```

Comment: блин, да такие календари есть навалом, меня интересует именно алгоритм составления такого календаря, программным путем....
пойду дискретную математику вспоминать....

Comment: @namak, а чем (серьезно) случайный подбор пар не устраивает ? Если Вы боитесь, что медленно, то гарантирую (для любого разумного числа команд) сосчитает, глазом моргнуть не успеете.

Comment: такое решение уже давно есть, тут уже скорее дело принципа...

а так - да, банально, список команд и готовый календарь, календарь не менять, а менять сами команды в списке команд местами, но это довольно скучно...

Comment: @namak, я не об этом ответе (банальном). Выше есть мое предложение ("методом грубой силы"). Случайный подбор это о нем.

Comment: идея интересная, т.е. выглядеть может примерно так:
в базе создаем табличку tours.
цикл
если а-б еще не играли
то добавить в базу

вот каким образом добавлять ИД тура и как разбивать на туры?
в табличку то ведь мы просто подряд все игры будем вносить?

Comment: один тур это n/2 игр, где n - количество команд

Comment: Попробовал и понял, что если количество команд не 2 в степени, то все усложняется. После первого тура (там для четного числа команд все OK) в туре могут сыграть не все команды, а количество туров в круге возрастает. 

Но решение этой проблемы IMHO автоматически решит проблему нечетного количества команд.

Кстати, @namak, в связи с этим "открытием" алгоритм со случайным выбором пар тоже должен усложниться (условие окончания генерации пар в туре).

--

@jmu,

    один тур это n/2 игр, где n - количество команд

к сожалению верно только для количества равного степени 2-х.

Comment: вот вот, казалось бы простеьнкий календарик, а тут целые "открытия" )))

Comment: если вам необходимо делать расписание на неопределенное количество команд то это решение явно не подходит. в противном случае лучше использовать уже сгенерированную сетку в которую случайным образом подставить id комманд. это даст возможность генерировать данные очень быстро (фактически подставить всего лишь 8 id)

Answer (score 0):

```
< ?php   
// массив команд   
$team = array('1'=>'1',   
        '2',   
        '3',   
        '4',   
        '5',   
        '6',   
        '7',   
        '8',   
        '9',   
        '10',   
        '11',   
        '12',   
        '13',   
        '14',   
        '15',   
        '16',   
        '17',   
        '18',   
        '19',   
        '20');   
$all_team = count($team);   
$k = $all_team/2;   

// 1 тур   
echo '1 тур<br>';   
for($i=1;$i< =$k;$i++)   
{   
    echo $team[$i].' - '.$team[($all_team-$i+1)].'<br>';   
}   

// Следующие туры   
for($i=2;$i< $all_team;$i++)   
{   
echo $i.' тур<br>';   

$team2 = $team[2];   

for($y=2;$y< $all_team;$y++)   
{   
    $team[$y] = $team[$y+1];   
}   
$team[$all_team] = $team2;   

for($j=1;$j<=$k;$j++)   
{   
    echo $team[$j].' - '.$team[($all_team-$j+1)].'<br>';   
}   

}   
?>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать чуть более развёрнутые вопросы.