# Сгенерировать турнирную сетку.

Tags: servlet, html, java

В общем ребята есть такой вопрос. С чего начать, что нужно знать, чтобы написать какой-то генератор турнирной сетки по какой-либо игре на Java + Servlet. Пока я не представляю с чего начать ;( .

Суть проста. Есть сайт, в нем есть кнопка создать турнир. При введенных данных, будет делаться турнир с самой сеткой и к ней матчами.

Буду благодарен за наводку в какую сторону податься. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Начните с изучения сервлетов) Head First "Servlets and JSP" - там одно из первых приложений Beer advicing. Там практически все, что вам нужно будет.

Опять же, заниматься сервлетами желательно, когда есть какой-то бэкграунд в джаве.

Comment: С сервлетами немного знаком. Спасибо, буду читать.

Answer (score 0):

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/80526)
 (на Хэшкоде) был подобный вопрос.

В ответах есть программка. Правда она на Си, но IMHO ее несложно переписать на Java.

Comment: Там группы, а мне именно нужно сетка, т.е. Play Off

Comment: Извините, перепутал. Тогда было свободное время, набросал человеку программку. 

На первый взгляд (а для степени 2-ки все очевидно элементарно) в алгоритме проблем нет. Берете в каждом круге соседние элементы массива (увеличивая индекс на 2) и помещаете победителей в новый массив. Повторяете, пока есть из кого выбирать.

В более сложном случае потенциально более сильных соперников надо разводить вначале по разным парам.

Видимо что-то в таком духе.